# Dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object returning nulls on iterative ctes

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, iteration, common-table-expression

Using: SQL SERVER 2016/2017

I am currently using the `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object` to retrieve output definitions for a large number of procedures.  I am seeing some unexpected results when it queries a tree navigation procedure.  I have traced the issue to being a problem with how the built in procedure identifies null objects in iterative cte's.

Code to replicate issue:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TestTable1;
DROP PROC IF EXISTS dbo.TestTableProc1;
DROP PROC IF EXISTS dbo.TestTableProc2;

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable1 (ParentID INT              NOT NULL
,                            ChildID  INT              NOT NULL
,                            Guid     UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL);
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.TestTableProc1 (@Value1 INT)
AS
    BEGIN;
        WITH cte AS
            (SELECT T1.ParentID
             ,      T1.ChildID
             ,      T1.Guid
               FROM dbo.TestTable1 T1
              WHERE T1.ParentID = @Value1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT T1.ParentID
             ,      T1.ChildID
             ,      T1.Guid
               FROM dbo.TestTable1 T1)
        SELECT  cte.ParentID
        ,       cte.ChildID
        ,       cte.Guid
          FROM  cte;
    END;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.TestTableProc2 (@Value1 INT)
AS
    BEGIN;
        WITH cte AS
            (SELECT T1.ParentID
             ,      T1.ChildID
             ,      T1.Guid
               FROM dbo.TestTable1 T1
              WHERE T1.ParentID = @Value1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT cte.ParentID
             ,      cte.ChildID
             ,      cte.Guid
               FROM dbo.TestTable1 T1
               JOIN cte ON T1.ParentID = cte.ChildID)
        SELECT  cte.ParentID
        ,       cte.ChildID
        ,       cte.Guid
          FROM  cte;
    END;
GO

SELECT  'dbo.TestTableProc1'
,       name
,       is_nullable
  FROM  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(OBJECT_ID('dbo.TestTableProc1'), 0)
UNION ALL
SELECT  'dbo.TestTableProc2'
,       name
,       is_nullable
  FROM  sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set_for_object(OBJECT_ID('dbo.TestTableProc2'), 0);

DROP PROC IF EXISTS dbo.TestTableProc1;
DROP PROC IF EXISTS dbo.TestTableProc2;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.TestTable1;
```

This gives the result set:

[image]

As you can see from the results `TestTableProc1` correctly identifies all fields as being not null. Where as `TestTableProc2` identifies all fields as being nullable, which they will never be.

As a solution to this I can move the entire process into a sub-procedure, and then call the sub-procedure with the current name and add a `WITH RESULTSET` clause to lock the output.  While this is a functioning workaround it would mean taking a performance hit and adding additional procedures to the database where they shouldn't be required.

What I need is a way to get the correct result set description as this is a rare call, and I can take some hit in performance here, rather than changing the main procedure itself.

Any options gratefully received.